# django - newsletter app - save outgoing data in models

Tags: django

I am trying to write my own newsletter app.

my vision is this:

I have a Model called `Newsletter`.

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
   added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   #data which is going out inside newsletter
```

I will send newsletter with some data like: hot news. these hot news are coming from another models.

How can I save those querysets (hot news from other models) into as Newsletter Object so that the user can later call some url and sees the newsletter with those data again.

Comment: Are you just asking how to save a model and create a view?

Comment: So, you are trying to add new field into Newsletter which will have foreign key to hot news or other model. You want to make that foreignkey generic. Am I right?

Comment: @SudipKafle yes. The thing is, in each instance of newsletter, i need to save many querysets from other models into one field of newsletter. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you are trying to have a relationship in data with not just one model but with any of the models. You can use django's [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Your model can be something similar to this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Newsletter(models.Model):
   added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   #data which is going out inside newsletter
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```